# Erro utilizando matplotlib

Tags: python, gráfico

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou começando a mexer com python e preciso gerar um gráfico de um txt, este está dividido em 3 colunas (onde representa x,y e z) e estas estão separadas por 3 espaços em branco. Ao plotar o gráfico, ele resulta na seguinte imagem: https://ibb.co/HD2DBMx

Não consigo identificar o erro, uma vez que já utilizei do MATLAB para realizar o desenho do gráfico desse TXT e o mesmo saiu da forma esperada.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#plt.style.use('classic')


x = []
y = []
z = []

dataset = open('TMM3_7mm.txt', 'r') # esse 'r' é apenas read, podia ser W para write


for line in dataset:
   line = line.strip() # 23,24\n -> 23,24
   X, Y, Z = line.split('   ') #Aqui é dito por qual valor as colunas tão separadas
   x.append(X)
   y.append(Y)
   z.append(Z)


dataset.close() # fecha a base de dados

plt.plot(x,y)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Partilha o txt com os dados.

Comment: https://github.com/GuilhermeWaldschmidtPereira/GuilhermeWaldschmidtPereira.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que estavas a passar strings para a função, plot. Quando carregas do txt os dados, ele são strings, precisa de ser convertido, para **float**. Tens aqui a documentação do package [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

```
def load_dataset():
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    dataset = open('TMM3_7mm.txt', 'r') # esse 'r' é apenas read, podia ser W para write

    for line in dataset:
       line = line.strip() # 23,24\n -> 23,24
       X, Y, Z = line.split('   ') #Aqui é dito por qual valor as colunas tão separadas
       x.append(X)
       y.append(Y)
       z.append(Z)

    x = [float(i) for i in x] # converte todo o array de strings para float
    y = [float(i) for i in y] # converte todo o array de strings para float
    z = [float(i) for i in z] # converte todo o array de strings para float

    dataset.close() # fecha a base de dados

    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.show()

load_dataset()
```

Com esta conversão obtive o seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]