# Python: soma condicional com condição variável

Tags: python, pandas, soma

bom dia.

A tarefa é a seguinte, estou tentando fazer uma curva 'a,b,c' de produtos por empresa. Tenho o seguinte df como exemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"empresa":["HST", "HST", "HST", "HSC", "HSC","HSC","HSC"],
               "produto":["prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4", "prod5", "prod6", "prod7"],
               "vl_total": [100,200,150,50,200,300,400]
               })
```

Para fazer a curva abc, é preciso criar uma coluna com a soma acumulada do valor total por empresa, e obter o seguinte valor (vl_acm):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"empresa":["HST", "HST", "HST", "HSC", "HSC","HSC","HSC"],
               "produto":["prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4", "prod5", "prod6", "prod7"],
               "vl_total": [100,200,150,50,200,300,400],
               "vl_acm": [100,300,450,50,250,550,950]
               })
```

No Excel é bem tranquilo fazer isso aplicando a função soma-se e colocando os valores da coluna 'empresa' como condicional, mas no Python não consegui achar uma forma de fazê-lo.

Desde já agradeço pessoal.

Comment: Viva, o que defines '**...tentando fazer uma curva...**'?? Analisa este post que fiz à tempos. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/444139/erro-utilizando-matplotlib/444339#444339 é isto que precisas? Coloca o exemplo do resultado que esperas obter e o código que já fizeste para conseguir isso.

Comment: Olá Ernesno. Estou me referindo à curva a,b,c de valor de produtos, é uma classificação muito utilizada em logística. Este post é sobre gráficos, não vi nenhuma relação com o que solicitei acima. O resultado que eu espero obter é a coluna 'vl_acm' do segundo dataframe que postei acima. Fiz ela manualmente para ilustrar, o que estou tentando é justamente gerar uma solução para calcular essa coluna em Python. Não postei código pois infelizmente não sei nem por onde começar... obrigado!

Comment: Ok, não sou especialista em logistica, logo não consegui inferir isso na tua questão, não ficou claro para quem não é especialista. Contudo, acho que deves tentar fazer algum código e depois partilhar se surgir problemas, só assim vais aprender

Comment: Sim, estou fazendo o possível. Infelizmente, com o conhecimento que tenho hoje, o mais próximo que consegui chegar foi criar uma coluna com o valor acumulado total, usando o código 'df['vl_acm'] = df['vl_total'].cumsum()', mas essa solução não respeita a coluna 'empresa' como condição, como eu preciso que seja feito. De toda forma, obrigado pelo comentário.

Answer (score 2):

Consegues efetuar essa soma usando o método `cumsum` após fazer o `groupby` por empresa:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"empresa":["HST", "HST", "HST", "HSC", "HSC","HSC","HSC"],
               "produto":["prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4", "prod5", "prod6", "prod7"],
               "vl_total": [100,200,150,50,200,300,400]
               })
df['vl_acm'] = df.groupby('empresa')['vl_total'].cumsum()
df

Out[2]:
    empresa produto vl_total    vl_acm
0   HST     prod1   100         100
1   HST     prod2   200         300
2   HST     prod3   150         450
3   HSC     prod4   50          50
4   HSC     prod5   200         250
5   HSC     prod6   300         550
6   HSC     prod7   400         950
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Caso tenha respondido à tua pergunta, não te esqueças de marcar a resposta como certa ;)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, sou iniciante, mas ainda assim vou tentar te ajudar porque acredito que eu tenha encontrado uma solução. Com certeza existem jeitos mais eficientes mas para te ajudar pensei da seguinte maneira:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"empresa":["HST", "HST", "HST", "HSC", "HSC","HSC","HSC"],
               "produto":["prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4", "prod5", "prod6", "prod7"],
               "vl_total": [100,200,150,50,200,300,400]
               })
filtro = df["empresa", "vl_total"] # Aqui você consegue colocar na váriavel filtro apenas
                                   # as colunhas 'empresa' e 'vl_total'
vl_acm = [] # Cria uma nova lista que será a coluna que você quer atribuir ao df
valores_dos_indices = [] # Cria um vetor para colocar os indices certos para posteriormente
                        # serem colocados os valores nas linhas corretas
for i in range(filtro["empresa"]): # O valor 'i' passará por todas as empresas
    if filtro["empresa"][i] == 'HSC': # Se a empresa correspondente ao indice 'i' for igual ao valor 'HSC'
        vl_acm.append(filtro["vl_total"][i]) # O valor da empressa  correspondente ao indice 'i' será atribuida ao vetor criado 
        valores_dos_indices.append(i)

df["vl_acm"] = [] # Cria uma nova coluna no df, por enquanto vazia
for i in valores_dos_indices: # Percorre todos os indices já marcados anteriormente
    df['vl_acm'].append(vl_acm[i]) # Preenche a nova coluna com os valores correspondentes
```

Era mais ou menos isso que você queria? Se não for, me explique melhor para que eu consiga te ajudar. Abs

Comment: Bom dia! meu caro, assim ficaria manual, pois eu teria que declarar a empresa. mas os métodos apontados pelo pessoal acima vão funcionar. Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar `pandas.groupby` pra agrupar por empresa, e em seguida `cumsum` pra fazer a soma cumulativa **pra cada grupo** (empresa).

Sabendo isso é questão de uma linha:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "empresa":["HST", "HST", "HST", "HSC", "HSC","HSC","HSC"], 
    "produto":["prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4", "prod5", "prod6", "prod7"], 
    "vl_total": [100,200,150,50,200,300,400]
})

df['vl_acm'] = df.groupby('empresa').cumsum()
```

DataFrame obtido ao final:

```
  empresa produto  vl_total  vl_acm
0     HST   prod1       100     100
1     HST   prod2       200     300
2     HST   prod3       150     450
3     HSC   prod4        50      50
4     HSC   prod5       200     250
5     HSC   prod6       300     550
6     HSC   prod7       400     950
```